# Separable differential equation in spherical coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider a function $f$ that satisfies the following differential equation:

\begin{equation}
\Delta f - \lambda^2 ((\Delta f)^2) = 0,
\end{equation}

where $\lambda$ is some real constant. Expressing $\Delta$ in spherical coordinates, does the differential equation admit separable solutions of the type $f(r,\theta,\phi) = R(r)\Theta(\theta)\Phi(\phi)$ or does this only makes sense if $\lambda = 0$?

Comment: When you use method of separation of variables, you are just looking for solutions in a particular form, So why not? Try and see if you can solve the equation.

Comment: The equation reads $$ \Delta  f (1- \lambda^2  \Delta f)=0.$$  Both possible zeros, the Laplace equation and the Helmholtz equation can be separated in spherical coordinates.